# ASP.NET MVC: Views using a model type that is loaded by MEF can't be found by the view engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mef

I'm attempting to create a framework for allowing controllers and views to be dynamically imported into an MVC application. Here's how it works so far:

- I'm using .NET 4, ASP.NET MVC 3 RC and the Razor ViewEngine
- Controllers are exported and imported using MEF per project - I call a set of controllers and views from a given project a "Module"
- Assemblies discovered using MEF are dynamically referenced by the BuildManager using a pre-application start method and `BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly`.
- Binaries (from exporting project) and Views are copied into the target project's folder structure using a build event
- Controllers are selected using a custom controller factory which inherits from DefaultControllerFactory and overrides GetControllerType()
- Views are selected using a custom view engine which inherits from RazorViewEngine and overrides GetView() and GetPartialView() to allow it to look for views in Module-specific view directories

Everything works so far *except* for views using a strongly typed model. Views that use the dynamic model work fine, but when I specify a model type using `@model`, I get a YSOD that says "The view 'Index' or its master was not found".

When debugging my ViewEngine implementation, I can see that:
`this.VirtualPathProvider.FileExists(String.Format(this.ViewLocationFormats[2], viewName, controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")))` returns true, while

`this.FileExists(controllerContext, String.Format(this.ViewLocationFormats[2], viewName, controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller")))` returns false.

Looking in Reflector, the RazorViewEngine implementation of `FileExists()` ultimately winds up doing this:

```
return (BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(virtualPath, false) != null);
```

However, I can't view `BuildManager.GetObjectFactory()` from Reflector because it's hidden somehow.

I'm suspecting that it has something to do with the fact that the model type is a type that is loaded from MEF, but since I'm already referencing the assemblies discovered by MEF from BuildManager, I'm out of leads. Can anyone provide a little more insight into what might be going on?

---

**Update:**
Turns out I was using an outdated version of Reflector from before .NET 4. I can see GetObjectFactory() now, but I can't really seem to find anything helpful. I've tried adding this into my FindView() overload:

try
 {
  var path = String.Format(this.ViewLocationFormats[2], viewName, controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"));
  var objFactory = System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetObjectFactory(virtualPath: path, throwIfNotFound: true);
 }
 catch
 {
 }

Unfortunately, `objFactory` ends up null, and no exception gets thrown. All the bits that deal with compilation errors are part of private methods or types so I can't debug any of that, but it even seems like they'd end up throwing an exception, which doesn't seem to be happening. Looks like I'm at a dead end again. Help!

---

**Update 2**

I've discovered that at the point where FindView() is being called, if I call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`, the assembly that the model type is in *is* included. However, I cannot load the type using `Type.GetType()`.

---

**Update 3**

Here's what I'm seeing:
[image: not found]

---

---

**Update 4**

Here's the ViewEngine implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Compilation;

namespace Site.Admin.Portal
{
    public class ModuleViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        private static readonly String[] viewLocationFormats = new String[]
        {
            "~/Views/{0}/{{1}}/{{0}}.aspx",
            "~/Views/{0}/{{1}}/{{0}}.ascx",
            "~/Views/{0}/{{1}}/{{0}}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.aspx",
            "~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.ascx",
            "~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml"
        };

        public ModuleViewEngine(IModule module)
        {
            this.Module = module;
            var formats = viewLocationFormats.Select(f => String.Format(f, module.Name)).ToArray();

            this.ViewLocationFormats = formats;
            this.PartialViewLocationFormats = formats;
            this.AreaViewLocationFormats = formats;
            this.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = formats;
            this.AreaMasterLocationFormats = formats;
        }

        public IModule Module { get; private set; }

        public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String partialViewName, Boolean useCache)
        {
            var moduleName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("module");
            if (moduleName.Equals(this.Module.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                return base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache);
            }
            else return new ViewEngineResult(new String[0]);
        }

        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, String viewName, String masterName, Boolean useCache)
        {
            var moduleName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("module");
            if (moduleName.Equals(this.Module.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                var baseResult = base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
                return baseResult;
            }
            else return new ViewEngineResult(new String[0]);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: BuildManager.GetObjectFactory isn't hidden (it's public, actually), but it _is_ new for .NET 4. Make sure you've opened the correct .NET libraries in Reflector.

Comment: GetObjectFactory doesn't normally throw; that's why we use it. The fact that it returned null usually means that the file wasn't found.

Comment: Oh, I see. In this case, the file is definitely there. When I remove the @model declaration, it works and returns an instance. When I put @model back in, it comes back null. Any suggestions for how to track down why?

Comment: Did you override the default Razor view base class in the Web.config file? If so, do you have both a non-generic and a generic version of the class? The former is used when there's no inherits or model directive; the latter is used when there's a model directive (the view then inherits from YourViewType<YourModelType>).

Comment: Nope, I don't have a custom view type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on Update 2, I'm guessing what you've got is an explicitly loaded copy of your assembly (that is, it was loaded through some other method than Load, like LoadFrom). Explicitly loaded assemblies are set off aside into a special place, because they are not allowed to satisfy implicit type requirements. The rules for Fusion (the assembly loader) can be pretty arcane and hard to understand.

I agree with Matthew's assessment that, to get this to work, your DLL is going to have to be in /bin or else it will never be able to satisfy the implicit type requirement.

Comment: You're correct, I'm using LoadFile to get an instance of the assembly. I'll see if I can figure out a different way to do it from MEF.

Comment: BINGO. I had to do a bit of ugly LINQ querying with my MEF catalogs, but I was able to get instances of the assemblies, now everything is working. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

The imported libaries aren't in the `/bin` directory so aren't probed when trying to resolve references.  I discovered a work around which I published in my [MVC + MEF article (Part 2)](http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=130).  Essentially you need to add your directories where your extensions sit to the probing path of the AppDomain.

Essentially where I am building my container:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates the composition container.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
protected virtual CompositionContainer CreateCompositionContainer()
{
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(MapPath("~/bin")));

    var config = CompositionConfigurationSection.GetInstance();
    if (config != null && config.Catalogs != null) {
        config.Catalogs
            .Cast<CatalogConfigurationElement>()
            .ForEach(c =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Path)) {
                    string path = c.Path;
                    if (path.StartsWith("~"))
                        path = MapPath(path);

                    foreach (var directoryCatalog in GetDirectoryCatalogs(path)) {

                        // Register our path for probing.
                        RegisterPath(directoryCatalog.FullPath);

                        // Add the catalog.
                        catalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    var provider = new DynamicInstantiationExportProvider();
    var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog, provider);
    provider.SourceProvider = container;

    return container;
}
```

I register all the directories of catalogs in the current domain:

```
/// <summary>
/// Registers the specified path for probing.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">The probable path.</param>
private void RegisterPath(string path)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(path);
}
```

I believe the same should work for MVC3.

**UPDATE**: Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't believe that ViewEngines are instantiated once per request, you create a single instance that you register with MVC.  Because of this only one `IModule` instance is ever used with your ViewEngine, so if a path doesn't match that first `IModule.Name` it won't be found? Does that make sense?

Comment: Interesting... Unfortunately, I tried using `AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath()`, and it didn't seem to help. I think it might effectively be doing the same thing as BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly(). Also, it's worth noting that I'm not seeing either of the errors screen capped in your article. I'll update my question with a screen cap of what I'm seeing.

Comment: I'm not embedding my views in the assemblies. The raw cshtml files are sitting within the folder structure of the executing project.

Comment: Lol, I realised that when I re-read the part about the VirtualPathProvider.  See my previous response, can we see what your ViewEngine is doing?

Comment: Matthew, you are correct - the ViewEngine is not instantiated for each request. I add one ViewEngine instance per Module type - so each module essentially has its own ViewEngine instance. I did this to allow each module's views to reside in their own folder within the Views folder.

Comment: Matthew - See the comments in Brad's answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually - man, I wish I could split the accepted answer points. Turns out I do still need the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath()` bit too. I'll come back in a couple days and see if I can give you bounty or something.

Comment: No problems mate, glad you got it sorted!